# Meteor and Phaser - error loading asset

Tags: javascript, meteor, phaser-framework

I run Phaser with Meteor I get an error when loading a .png file from the directory. Could someone please provide some guidance on how to fix it.

My environment is

```
ubuntu 14.04
Meteor 1.1.0.2
Phaser v2.3.0
```

My directory structure and folders are

```
cmt@ubuntu:~/projects/myMeteorProjects/issueReplication2$ ls -R
.:
client  index.css  index.html  public  server

./client:
client.js   phaser.js

./public:
car.png
```

index.html is

```
<head>
  <title>phaser and meteor</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Phaser and Meteor</h1>

  {{> game1}}
</body>

<template name="game1">
  {{phaserGame}}
```

client.js is

```
Template.game1.helpers({
    phaserGame: function() {
    var game = new Phaser.Game(320,320, Phaser.AUTO, 'firstGame', { preload:
 preload, create: create, update:update }); 
    return game;

    function preload() {
        game.load.image('car', './public/car.png');
    }

    function create() {
        car = game.add.sprite(50, 50, 'car');
    }

    function update() {
    }

    function moveBullets (bullet) { 
    }

    function accelerateToObject(obj1, obj2, speed) {
    }
    }
})
```

and finally the error in Chrome is

```
Phaser.Loader - image[car]: error loading asset from URL ./public/car.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change from `'./public/car.png'` to `'/car.png'`

Comment: Why would this work? How would phaser, know where to find that resource?