# Meteor + Phaser/Pixi

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have two issues to expose.

First: I'm working on a website and I'm doing its structure using Meteor to deal with front-end back-end and database all together since I don't have that much experience working with a large variety of interfaces. I'm liking Meteor but I need to add animated graphics (mainly 2d animations) and I'm thinking of using Phaser or Pixi but I'm not really sure if any of those is the right tool (I'm not trying to do a game, just animations). I would like to know if there is any other tool that is best suited for doing what I have described before.

Second: I already made some experiments with phaser, I dowloaded the phaser package for meteor from atmosphere js but I can't even load the images to the browser. It seems that phaser cannot load the images(although the paths are correct) but Meteor sends a 200 OK response to the browser that is empty and also the type on the header is wrong, it says text/html, when it should say image/png. My problem relates to this question [Meteor and Phaser - error loading asset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31736758/meteor-and-phaser-error-loading-asset) but the solution presented didn't worked for me.

My file structure:

npm-debug.log       phaser-test.html    public
phaser-test.css     phaser-test.js

My phaser-test.js:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

    Template.game.helpers({

        game: function(){

          var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, '', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update });

          function preload() {

              game.load.image('sky', 'public/sky2.png');
              game.load.image('ground', 'public/platform.png');
              game.load.image('star', '/star.png');
              game.load.spritesheet('dude', 'public/dude.png', 32, 48);


         }

         function create() {

             game.add.sprite(100, 100 , 'star');
             game.add.sprite(300, 300 , 'ground');  
             game.add.sprite(150, 150, 'sky');  
             game.add.sprite(200, 200, 'dude');  
        }

        function update() {


        }

     }

  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.startup(function () {
       // code to run on server at startup
    });
}
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your images are under the `public` folder at the root of your app then you don't need the `/public/` in your urls. `public` maps to `/`. i.e. `public/dude.png` should just be `dude.png`. Usually I just have a `public/images` folder in my project and then I refer to images using `/images/name.png`

Comment: Thank you very much Michel, that indeed solved my problem!